# how do I make my horizontal scroll bar to work in my codes that uses tkinter library

Tags: python, tkinter

below are my codes

when you click the run script button it populates the frame with df of random numbers I can scroll down but not across. Any reason why? Can someone fix the code please? I dont want to change the position of the treeframe as I have other button and labels on the left what I have removed from my codes for simplicity.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# root = Tk()

# root.geometry("1200x800")

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x800")

frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

def treeframe1(rows, df):
    tree["columns"] = list(range(1, len(df.columns) + 1))
    tree['show'] = 'headings'
    tree['height'] = '30'

    colnames = df.columns

    tree.column(1, width=90, anchor='c')
    tree.heading(1, text=colnames[0])

    for i in range(2, len(df.columns) + 1):
        tree.column(i, width=100, anchor='c')
        tree.heading(i, text=colnames[i - 1])

    for i in rows:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=i)


tree = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode='browse', height='30')
tree.place(x=830, y=45)
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
vsb.place(x=820, y=45, height=560)
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=tree.xview)
vsb.place(x=820, y=670, width=200)
tree.configure(xscrollcommand=vsb.set)

def view_command():
    global action_type
    global df
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(100,150)))
    rows = df.values.tolist()
    treeframe1(rows, df)

b4 = Button(root, text="run script", width=15, height=11, command=view_command)
b4.place(x=500, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Right now the whole `Treeview` is shown on the screen (because you used `tree.place(...)`) so there is nothing to scroll. If you limit the width of the `Treeview`, the horizontal scroll bar will work. Please read how `tkinter` geometry managers work.

Comment: agreed, no but when you click the "run script" button you will have a large dataframe populating the tree, may be increase the size to 300 columns from 150 to make it even bigger and then you will see the inability to scroll across

Comment: When you use `.place(...)`, the window doesn't get information about the width of the widget and can't tell the widget that it's being cut it off. So right now as far as `tkinter` knows the whole `Treeview` is shown. You need to limit the width of the `Treeview`.

Comment: ok thanks, didnt know that as I come from non tech background so its all trail and error for me. so when you say limit the width what did you meant by that? can you amend the code and drop it here? all I want to when my output populates the tree I should be able to scroll horizontally or vertically.

Comment: You can set the `width` option in `tree.place(...)`, like what you did on the horizontal scrollbar.